# Serialize input in JS return string in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a little issues with my JS code.

I have a AJAX and I want to get the variable in PHP.

All works fine except the "param" data.

here is the code:

```
$('#signup_submit').click(function (event){
    param = jQuery('input').filter(function() {
                     return this.name.match(/param/);
                }).serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: result.php,
        data: {
            action: 'submit_ajax',
            email: $('#email').val(),
            send_welcome: true,
            listId:  $('#listid').val(),
            param: param
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
});
```

The result var_dump for the param (PHP):

```
 param%5Bconfirmation%5D=1
```

it should be something like:

```
array(1){ 'confirmation'=>1 }
```

Any idea to fix it?

thanks

Comment: Create an associative array in a for loop and then `json_encode` the array and echo it back to js.

Comment: try calling console.log(param) and tell us the result pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted `$param` var looks like `param[confirmation]=1`

And you need `parse_str` function to get serialized data:

```
parse_str($param, $output);
```

**Output**

```
var_dump($output);

array(1) {
  ["param"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["confirmation"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Or get specific index directly:

```
parse_str($param);
echo $confirmation; // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) instead of serialize.

```
param = jQuery('input').filter(function() {
    return this.name.match(/param/);
}).serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is because `param` is being dual-encoded, once by `.serialize()`:

```
param = jQuery('input')....serialize();

console.log(param);
// "param%5Bconfirmation%5D=1"
```

And, again for `data:`, which is run through `$.param()` by `$.ajax()`:

```
console.log($.param({
    param: param
}));
// "param=param%255Bconfirmation%255D%3D1"
```

While the 1st round of encoding is decoded for `$_POST`:

```
var_dump($_POST['param']);
// string(25) "param%5Bconfirmation%5D=1"
```

You'll have to manually decode the 2nd round with [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$param = array();
parse_str($_POST['param'], $param);

var_dump($param);
// array(1) { ["confirmation"]=> int(1) }
```

---

You can also try to avoid the dual-encoding by concatenating `param` with the other encoded data:

```
data: param + '&' + $.param({
    action: 'submit_ajax',
    email: $('#email').val(),
    send_welcome: true,
    listId:  $('#listid').val()
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

%5B is [
%5D is ]

you could use this function to fix the encoding before you submit

```
function fixedEncodeURI (str) {
    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
}
```

Like so:

```
$('#signup_submit').click(function (event){
    param = jQuery('input').filter(function() {
                     return this.name.match(/param/);
                }).serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: result.php,
        data: {
            action: 'submit_ajax',
            email: $('#email').val(),
            send_welcome: true,
            listId:  $('#listid').val(),
            param: fixedEncodeURI(param)
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
});
```